# Pushing metrics to collector

Tags: open-telemetry

I am fairly new to OpenTelemetry, I've got a C# app that will be pushing out metrics to an HTTP endpoint. Ideally, this will be the OpenTelemetry collector pod in our Kubernetes cluster. I've got the following receiver configuration, but I don't know if this is the right way to set up the receiver since we don't have the application running to test the metrics receiver.

```
receivers:
  prometheus:
    config:
      - job_name: my_csharp_app
        static_configs:
        - targets: ["otel-collector.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:$PORT"]


processors:
  resourcedetection:
    detectors: [gcp]
    timeout: 10s

  transform:
    # "location", "cluster", "namespace", "job", "instance", and "project_id" are reserved, and
    # metrics containing these labels will be rejected.  Prefix them with exported_ to prevent this.
    metric_statements:
    - context: datapoint
      statements:
      - set(attributes["exported_location"], attributes["location"])
      - delete_key(attributes, "location")
      - set(attributes["exported_cluster"], attributes["cluster"])
      - delete_key(attributes, "cluster")
      - set(attributes["exported_namespace"], attributes["namespace"])
      - delete_key(attributes, "namespace")
      - set(attributes["exported_job"], attributes["job"])
      - delete_key(attributes, "job")
      - set(attributes["exported_instance"], attributes["instance"])
      - delete_key(attributes, "instance")
      - set(attributes["exported_project_id"], attributes["project_id"])
      - delete_key(attributes, "project_id")

  batch:
    # batch metrics before sending to reduce API usage
    send_batch_max_size: 200
    send_batch_size: 200
    timeout: 5s

  memory_limiter:
    # drop metrics if memory usage gets too high
    check_interval: 1s
    limit_percentage: 65
    spike_limit_percentage: 20

# Note that the googlemanagedprometheus exporter block is intentionally blank
exporters:
  googlemanagedprometheus:

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [prometheus]
      processors: [batch, memory_limiter, resourcedetection, transform]
      exporters: [googlemanagedprometheus]
```

Any help is appreciated!

So far we've tried using the GCP template to scrape pods in the cluster, unfortunately we do not want to scrape this application, only receive metrics being pushed from it.